# Selecting appropriate JAR files to run map reduce from eclipse

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have hadoop 2.0.0 CDH -4.7.0 installed . I want to set up my eclipse to run my own map reduce programs but I am not sure which hadoop jAR files to add as a reference . I have added all jar files but that didn't work for me .
Can any one please help me to get the list of jar files and their location in cdh 4.7.0 to run mr job from eclipse ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is depend on your program that which type of function you are used. [image]

In this image jar names are showing. This is compulsory for simple hadoop map reduce program.

Comment: Can you please list out all required jar files in order to run any type of mr job ..

Comment: in this case add all jar which are in hadoop/lib folder and also add all jar from hadoop folder. After adding jar almost type of mr program will run.